# Angular command - ng serve is not working on Visual Studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

i have created a Angular project .when i try to Run "ng serve" command ,an error showed up.

> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this  system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
>
> - ng serve
> - ~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 0):

> 1.open PowerShell (**as an administrator**).
>
> 2."Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"
>
> 3.choose - Y

run **ng serve** again. now its working...